# Synchronizing simultaneous UIImageView animations

Tags: ios, animation, uiimageview, uibutton

I have three keypads on a UIScrollView, where each keypad is a column of buttons. When I get an update for button state (where the keypad is acting as a delegate) I have certain button images that respond to this change of state - On, Off, and two On/Off animations (1 Hz and 10 Hz). Right now I have all that working, but I need to properly synchronize all the animations. The code I have synchronizes animations on a single keypad but not all the keypads on a page (this is in the KeypadController):

```
#pragma mark -
#pragma mark LEDDelegate

- (void)LEDUpdated:(LED *)sender {
    // Search through our LEDs for a match on the updating LED. This gives us
    // the button index so we can update properly.
    int ledIndex = -1; // Needs to be zero indexed
    Component *tempComp;
    LED *tempLED;
    for (NSUInteger itemCount = 0; itemCount < [taskButtonTitleCollection count]; ++itemCount) {
        tempComp = (Component *) [taskButtonTitleCollection objectAtIndex:itemCount];
        if ([[tempComp getComponentType] isEqualToString:@"LED" ]){
            tempLED = (LED *) [tempComp getComponentElement];
            ledIndex++;
            if (tempLED == sender) {
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    //Code for selecting images here - removed for brevity    

    // Declare the image we're about to use
    UIImage *newNormal, *newHighlight, *newBlink;

    // Going to need the button for flashing
    UIButton *btn = [buttonCollection objectAtIndex:ledIndex];

    // For syncing animation, part 1
    // TODO: This syncs a single keypad, which means we don't sync between columns
    NSMutableArray *buttonsToSync = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    for (UIButton *active in buttonCollection) {
        if ([[active imageView] isAnimating]) {
            [[active imageView] stopAnimating];
            if (active != btn) {
                [buttonsToSync addObject:active];
            }
        }  
    }

    // Grab the updated state of the current led object so we can select the
    // correct button images
    switch ([tempLED state]) {
        case LED_STATE_ON:
            newNormal = [[Utils getImageNamed:pressedImage] stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:0.0 topCapHeight:0.0];

            newHighlight = [[Utils getImageNamed:highlightedImage] stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:0.0 topCapHeight:0.0];
            break;

        case LED_STATE_FLASH1: // 1 Hz blinking
            newNormal = [[Utils getImageNamed:normalImage] stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:0.0 topCapHeight:0.0];
            newBlink = [[Utils getImageNamed:pressedImage] stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:0.0 topCapHeight:0.0];

            // We can animate between these two images at the correct
            // speed with the below code.
            [[btn imageView] setAnimationImages:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:newNormal, newBlink, nil]];
            [[btn imageView] setAnimationDuration:1];
            [buttonsToSync addObject:btn];

            newHighlight = [[Utils getImageNamed:highlightedImage] stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:0.0 topCapHeight:0.0];
            break;

        case LED_STATE_FLASH2: // 10 Hz blinking
            newNormal = [[Utils getImageNamed:normalImage] stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:0.0 topCapHeight:0.0];
            newBlink = [[Utils getImageNamed:pressedImage] stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:0.0 topCapHeight:0.0];

            // We can animate between these two images at the correct
            // speed with the below code.
            [[btn imageView] setAnimationImages:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:newNormal, newBlink, nil]];
            [[btn imageView] setAnimationDuration:0.1];
            [buttonsToSync addObject:btn];

            newHighlight = [[Utils getImageNamed:highlightedImage] stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:0.0 topCapHeight:0.0];
            break;

        case LED_STATE_OFF:
        default:
            newNormal = [[Utils getImageNamed:normalImage] stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:0.0 topCapHeight:0.0];

            newHighlight = [[Utils getImageNamed:normalImageWithoutShadow] stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:0.0 topCapHeight:0.0];
            break;
    }

    // Set the new button images for the normal and highlighted states
    [btn setImage:newNormal forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [btn setImage:newHighlight forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
    newNormal = nil, newBlink = nil, newHighlight = nil;

    // For syncing animation, part 2
    // TODO: This syncs a single keypad, which means we don't sync between columns
    for (UIButton *active in buttonsToSync) {
        [[active imageView] startAnimating];
    }       
}
```

Again, this synchronizes the animations for one keypad but not all.

One possible solution I came up with was making all animations start at some multiple of the system time (as close to on a second as possible, for example), but I couldn't come up with a working approach that would do that. I tried adding this in front of part 2 of the syncing (where I restart animations):

```
NSDate *date = [NSDate date];
double timePassed_ms = [date timeIntervalSince1970] * 1000.0;

while ( (int)timePassed_ms % 500 != 0) {
    timePassed_ms = [date timeIntervalSince1970] * 1000.0;
}
```

Unfortunately that doesn't work (infinite looping and blocking the GUI). I'm guessing that's because I never poll at exactly the right time.

Is there a way to do what I want?